# Anonymous Struct Pointer

Tags: c

Suppose we have a piece of code:

```
int random_function random_variable                                   
  (                                                                 
   struct   struct_name *               
  );
```

Would this be valid syntax? If so, how does one reference the pointer later in the program?

Answer (score 3):

No, the sample code is not valid syntax.  A compiling attempt will show that.

Re-writing into what it appears you are asking is the following example, you ask "how does one reference the (anonymous struct) pointer later in the program?"

```
int random_function(int random_variable) {
  // Supposed Anonymous Struct Pointer, but invalid syntax.
  struct struct_name *;  
}
```

It appears you are mixing what is *anonymous*.  Your example hints that you think the structure has a name and the variable is *anonymous*, which if could happen would make it inaccessible.

A correct example of Anonymous Struct Pointer would be

```
int random_function(int random_variable) {
  struct /* no structure tag here */ {
    int a;
    int b;
  } *variable_name;
  variable_name = malloc(sizeof *variable_name);
  variable_name->a = 1;
  variable_name->a = 2;
  return variable_name->a;
}
```

Here you can see the structure has no tag, that makes it an anonymous structure.  `variable_name` becomes a pointer to an anonymous structure .  The variable is accessed in the usual ways.

Comment: I don't think `sizeof` can know the correct size of an unnamed struct. See this: https://asciinema.org/a/nbsd9MQxMOOmM2e73l4SI1o2P

Comment: @ifelsemonkey Agreed.  Code amended.